# uninitialized constant UserJob::Delayed::Job

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, associations, delayed-job, ruby-on-rails-3.2

**Introduction**

I am following the tutorial here and I have got to the last bit and I am getting a error.
I am using Ruby 1.9 and Rails 3.2.

**Problem**

The error below happens when it hits this line of code...

```
@user_job.job = @job
```

**Error message**

uninitialized constant UserJob::Delayed::Job

**Full Trace**

```
activerecord (3.2.3) lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:119:in `compute_type'
activerecord (3.2.3) lib/active_record/reflection.rb:172:in `klass'
activerecord (3.2.3) lib/active_record/associations/association.rb:202:in `raise_on_type_mismatch'
activerecord (3.2.3) lib/active_record/associations/belongs_to_association.rb:6:in `replace'
activerecord (3.2.3) lib/active_record/associations/singular_association.rb:17:in `writer'
activerecord (3.2.3) lib/active_record/associations/builder/association.rb:51:in `block in define_writers'
app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:8:in `index'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:414:in `_run__2107776697662030787__process_action__219357298770380196__callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:205:in `process_action'
activerecord (3.2.3) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:203:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:246:in `block in action'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:36:in `call'
journey (1.0.3) lib/journey/router.rb:68:in `block in call'
journey (1.0.3) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `each'
journey (1.0.3) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:600:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `context'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:200:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:338:in `call'
activerecord (3.2.3) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
activerecord (3.2.3) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:467:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__2493773234006611680__call__1862807147047497298__callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:65:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call_app'
railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:62:in `call'
railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/application.rb:220:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
/Users/billyshambrook/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
/Users/billyshambrook/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
/Users/billyshambrook/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'
```

The issue seems to be with the association.

```
class UserJob < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :job, :class_name => "Delayed::Job"
 ...
```

Is this the correct way to state a association with the DelayedJobs table?

The versions of delayed job being used are

```
delayed_job (3.0.2)
  activesupport (~> 3.0)
delayed_job_active_record (0.3.2)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your class name option to `::Delayed::Job`. The leading :: causes the class to be searched from from the top level whereas at the moment it is searching for a `Delayed::Job` class nested within your `UserJob` class

Comment: Legend, that is perfect. Thanks Frederick!